# Possible to SSO / SAML DocuSign eSignature with Okta?

Tags: single-sign-on, docusignapi, saml, saml-2.0, okta

I am on the IT team at Segment and in the process of reviewing how DocuSign eSignature is used at Segment. I have a few questions:

1) Would it be possible to SSO / SAML with Okta?

2) If so, do you have any documentation as to how to SSO / SAML this application, specifically with Okta?

3) Is there a contact that can assist with getting this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is absolutely possible.
If you are a customer and need help - contact Customer Support.
Here is the guide for SSO - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-identity-providers.
You can try this in the Sandbox (demo) environment first and see if it works before enabling this in Production.